# Matlab 2017a Linux Deployed executable (Error: Undefined function or variable 'matlabrc')

Tags: linux, matlab

I have been occasionally (not always) getting the error  `Undefined function or variable 'matlabrc'` or `Undefined function or variable 'ctfroot'` when trying to run Matlab created executable on Linux.

I am creating the executable with the following command.

```
mcc -mv foo.m
```

It used to run fine but I started seeing this error and do not have an idea how to fix it. Can I change something in the build process to make it more reliable for my executable to successfully run.

I use the following command to run the executable.

```
./run_foo.sh <path_to_matlab_2017a>
```

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There might be an issue with your MATLAB installation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: After continued digging, I found that the MCR cache had somehow gotten corrupted. The solution was to delete the entire cache ($HOME/.mcrCache9.2 in my case). I also added "export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=$PWD" to all of my scripts so that when a large number of jobs are running, they use their own cache reducing the chances of corruption.